# is there any way to list restful webservices

Tags: ibm-bpm

I'm new to IBM BPM.  I'm trying to create a web service for a class i'm taking but the instructor/site architect is unavailable at the moment.

Is there some way to determine the different types of RESTful calls available at a particular IBM BPM url?

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is, that you would like to see which calls are supported by the IBM BPM REST API, is this correct?

You can discover the calls via the REST API Tester which can be found by the following URL:

> http://{host}:{port}/bpmrest-ui

In this web-interface you can see different REST APIs, calls and you can build your own rest services with the provided input forms.

Source and further documentation: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/1108_thaker/1108_thaker.html